# multidimentional array show values in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to display values from my api which are object inside object. This is have i think should be, is it correct, how can i display them ?

```
$scope.tagy = function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.inventories.length;i++){
        for(var j = 0; j < $scope.inventories[i].tags.length;j++){
            $scope.alltags = $scope.inventories[i].tags[j].name;
        }
    }
    return $scope.alltags;
};
```

my api something like this

```
  objects: [
    {
       ....
        something else
       ...
    tags: [
        {
        id: 20,
        name: "secondnewtag",
        resource_uri: "/api/v1/tags/20",
        slug: "secondnewtag"
        },
        {
        id: 21,
        name: "newtag",
        resource_uri: "/api/v1/tags/21",
        slug: "newtag"
        }
     ]
    }
   ]
```

Comment: Only the last tag will be in alltags since it's not an array. What is your expected result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Florian noted, to get all the tags, use an array.

```
$scope.tags = [];
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.inventories.length;i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < $scope.inventories[i].tags.length;j++){
        $scope.tags.push($scope.inventories[i].tags[j].name);
    }
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/mUQ9SgVw3kfszNyUmiRW